# Can we obtain hybrid algorithm for spam filtering from Naive Bayes & SVM?

Tags: svm, libsvm, bayesian, email-spam, spam-prevention

I am developing a spam filtering application. I need suggestions regarding the hybrid algorithm from Naive Bayes & SVM.(e.g. based on feature vector, probabilities). Any help is appreciated. Can we develop hybrid algorithm from Naive bayes & SVM?

Comment: Look into boosting algorithms. AdaBoost in particular.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why would you want to merge these two specific methods, but you could use [ensemble learning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ensemble_learning) methods for that.

EDIT: based on your comments, it seems  you already have two independently trained classifiers, and would like to use them together for classification. One possible method for doing that would be to co-calibrate the classifier results, e.g. via summing and thresholding.

That is: given an input, e.g. an email, both Naive Bayes and SVM generate a real valued result; let's denote these results *nb* and *svm* . 
You could use linear regression to find coefficients *c1* and *c2* and a threshold *t*, so that you'd classify an email as spam only if *c1* * *nb* + *c2* * *svm* > *t*. You could, of course, use more elaborate methods, but with some luck this would give a slightly better performance than each classifier independently.

Comment: I am trying to obtain new improved method for spam filtering application. to achieve that, if possible can u suggest something?

Comment: Edited with a specific suggestion for the case you're describing.

Comment: thanks.... thts very helpful...I guess I can use that.. what I did is, I used the probabilities to build a feature vector in case of SVM,probabilities are calculated in NB.

Comment: Can u more elaborate , how can I calculate real valued result nb & svm ? I mean how to express in real value?

Comment: Assuming you refer to how to technically get these values, this would depend on the packages you use - try the documentation.